# Getting nil values when `map`-ing over array of entities

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm using Core Data in an iOS app and executing the following Swift code which results in an error at the second line:

```swift
let movies = (try? container.newBackgroundContext().fetch(request)) ?? []
return movies.map { $0.name! } // error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping...
```

Note that in the example above it's 100% certain that there is no entity in `movies` with `nil` in `name`. The corresponding attribute in the Core Data model is set to **not optional**.

When I change the code as shown below (i.e. not inlining `newBackgroundContext()`) there is no error:

```swift
let context = container.newBackgroundContext()
let movies = (try? context.fetch(request)) ?? []
return movies.map { $0.name! } // no error this time
```

I'm quite new to Swift and assume it has something to do with memory management (e.g. `context` is deinited prematurely) but I would appreciate an actual explanation of why the error occurs in the first code listing.

Comment: If *it's 100% certain that there is no entity in movies with `nil` in name* declare `name` in the Core Data model as non-optional. This avoids issues like that. In Swift it's highly recommended to use non-optional types as much as possible.

Comment: @vadian Thank you but I've done this already. The problem there is that the non-optional flag only applies when the data is written, not when it is read so that's not a solution.

Comment: If you had *done this already* you would get a compiler error that `name` cannot be force unwrapped because `name` is non-optional. And you are strongly discouraged from ignoring `thrown` Core Data errors with `try?`

Comment: Sorry @vadian but this is not correct. If it was, the fixed code in my second code listing would not solve the problem, would it?

Comment: If you use newBackgroundContext() then you should also be using the background context by calling `perform` or `performAndWait` I believe. Not sure what happens when you call `fetch` directly like that. Off topic but are you sure you want to map your objects like that instead of returning an array of model (Movie?) objects. Remember that Core Data is an object mapper framework and not a database.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you run map function on your array it returns an optional value. seems like there is no value in name and you are doing force unwrapping. try to use compactMap.

```
movies.compactMap { $0.name }
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using force unwrapping because I know the name is not nil so there must be another issue.

Comment: Can you debug and share movies result and see whats the value in name

Comment: Check vadian comment